# iOS lldb function lookup

Tags: ios, debugging, jailbreak, remote-debugging, lldb

I am trying to learn how to debug iOS apps on my jailbroken iOS device using lldb.

I can't seem to figure out why lldb is not able to get functions when gdb is able to. For example, I am trying to find out what is the _mh_execute_header address.

On GDB

```
(gdb) info func _mh_ex*
All functions matching regular expression "_mh_ex*":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x000e5000  _mh_execute_header
```

On lldb

```
(lldb) image lookup -r -n _mh_e*
(lldb) image lookup -r -s _mh_e*
(lldb)
```

I did some searching around and found this site: http://versprite.com/og/ios-reverse-engineering-part-one-configuring-lldb/ and followed its instructions.

After executing the target create command:

```
(lldb) target create --arch arm Cood
Current executable set to '/Users/tester/Desktop/Cood' (armv7).
```

I can do this

```
(lldb) image lookup -r -n _mh_e*
(lldb) image lookup -r -s _mh_e*
1 symbols match the regular expression '_mh_e*' in /Users/tester/Desktop/Cood:
    Address: Cood[0x00004000] (Cood.__TEXT + 0)
    Summary: Cood`_mh_execute_header
```

But then I execute process continue and I get

```
(lldb) process continue 
error: invalid process
```

I have no idea what is going on.

FYI, I executed the following commands on my Mac to connect to the iOS debug server (OS X Yosemite, Xcode 6.3.1, lldb-330.0.44)

```
(lldb) platform select remote-ios
(lldb) process connect connect://127.0.0.1:7777
(lldb) process attach -n Cood -w
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Any solution for that ?

Comment: How did you get gdb onto ios? What version of ios are you running? I have tried with the package in cydia and it does not work on ios 9.3.3?

Comment: @JesseSanford I'm using lldb not gdb. I suggest you use lldb, it's the only debugger supported by iOS

Comment: @JesseSanford putting GDB should be available to you. Open Cydia.Add repo: http://cydia.radare.org  and search for gdb. Hope that helps.